# Remove ESRI logo from map with Silverlight API v2.1

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api

Is there a way to remove the ESRI logo from the map display with the ESRI Silverlight API v2.1.  This was possible in the 1.x version, but the old method no longer works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does [Map.IsLogoVisible=False](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/2.1/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Map~IsLogoVisible.html) work?

Answer (score 6):

Map.IsLogoVisible=False is correct.  However, if you are using one of ESRI's tile services there is no way to hide that logo.