# Removing Esri logo from ArcGIS Viewer for Flex 2.2?

Tags: arcgis-flex-viewer

How can we remove the Esri logo from ArcGIS Viewer for Flex 2.2?

Logo layer is set to be visible by default.

Is there a way to turn it off?

Comment: did you see Seth's question here...   http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3290/remove-esri-logo-from-map-with-silverlight-api-v2-1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should read license agreements here:
http://www.esri.com/legal/pdfs/mla_e204_e300/english.pdf

4.2 (g)
 Licensee shall not remove or obscure any Esri or its licensors' patent, copyright, trademark, or proprietary rights notices 
contained in or affixed to Software, Data, Web Services, or Documentation.

Comment: well i sure did not read the agreement, thank you so very much

Comment: ...can i have the overview map open then by default? :)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible in the APIs by setting the property [logoVisible](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/flex/apiref/com/esri/ags/Map.html#logoVisible) on the Map to false.